# ReferenceError: window is not defined in typescript

Tags: typescript, barcode-scanner

I am making a barcode scanner to scan both code128 and pdf417 and I am using react-qr-barcode-scanner to do so in typescript. However I get this error when running the code:

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

Here is my code: (ScannerTest.tsx)

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import BarcodeScannerComponent from 'react-qr-barcode-scanner';


export const ScannerTest = () => {
    const [camera, setCamera] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState("Not Found");
    return (
        <div >
            <div>SCANNER!</div>
            <button onClick={() => setCamera(!camera)}>
                {camera ? "Stop" : "Start"}
            </button>
            <div className="container">
                {camera &&
                    <div>
                        <BarcodeScannerComponent
                            width={500}
                            height={500}
                            onUpdate={(err, result) => {
                                if (result) {
                                    setData(result?.text)
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                        <p>{data}</p>
                    </div>}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ScannerTest;
```

How can I avoid this error?